# No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]

Tags: for-loop, groovy

What's wrong with dynamic snippet `2(i-1)` at **inner for loop** in following groovy code? If I replace it with `2i` or `i+1` or any hardcoded number(eg `6`) [works fine](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Nested-for-loops-in-Groovy-td345898.html).

```
  1     class Algorithms {
  2      static def printTriangle(n){
  3           for(i in 1..n){
  4            if(i>1){
  5               for(j in 1..2(i-1)){ print 1 }
  6             } else { print 1 } } //end of inner loop
  7               println ""
  8           } //end of outer loop
  9       }

 24       static def main(args){

 26            printTriangles(4)
 27       }
 28   }
```

The stacktrace is

```
1
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), abs(), wait(long), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), abs(), wait(long), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at Algorithm.printTriangle(Algorithm.groovy:5)
    at Algorithm$printTriangle.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at Algorithm.main(Algorithm.groovy:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aghh, I wasn't doing mathematics, following code works.

```
  for(j in 1..2*(i-1)){}
```